# BST: Constructor Node in class. Node cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes

I'm trying to implement a BST. I am working on adding a key and value to a Node. This is what I have so far. But I kept getting

```
constructor Node in class EMD<K,V>. Node cannot be applied to given types. 
required: no arguments; found K,V;
```

How do I fix this?

```
class EMD<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements RangeMap<K,V> {
    class Node {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        KVPair<K,V> kv;
    }

private Node root;

public void add(K key, V value) {
    // TODO: Implement me(basic score)
    root = add (root, key, value);
}
private Node add(Node x, K key, V value){
    if (x == null){
        return new Node (key, value);
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
        if (cmp < 0){
            x.left = add(x.left, key, value);}
            else if (cmp > 0 ){
                x.right = add(x.right, key, value);}
                else if (cmp == 0){
                    x.value = value;} 
                }
                    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, if you do not supply an explicit constructor, then the compiler will insert an implicit, no-arg, or "default", constructor for you that does nothing but call its superclass constructor.  This is happening for your `Node` class.

However, when you attempt to create a `Node` on this line:

```
return new Node (key, value);
```

You are attempting to pass 2 parameters to a default, no-arg constructor, hence the error.  Java doesn't automatically take parameters and assign them one at a time to instance variables.  That's not how constructors work in Java.

You can declare your `Node` constructor that takes 2 parameters explicitly, in your `Node` class.

```
Node(K k, V v) {
    // Use k and v appropriately here.
}
```

Comment: would this be correct?   class Node {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        KVPair<K,V> kv;
        K key;
        V value;
        public Node(K key, V value) {
   this.key = key;
   this.value = value;
  }
    }